# Prove that if $(X,\tau)$ is a discrete topological space, then every open set is a clopen set.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $(X,\tau)$ is a discrete topological space, then every open set is a clopen set.

I don't understand the method of what I have to prove. If I assume that $A_i \in \tau$ are open sets, then I have to prove that they are also closed. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What is the definition of openness? And what is the discrete space?

Comment: The arbitrary union of open sets is open. Any set can then be written as the union of its elements where each element is open.

Comment: OK, but how do I use that information?

Comment: So if we know every set is open, for instance the set $A$, what can we say about $X-A$? Is this set open? Closed? What does that imply about $A$?

Comment: I have to prove that it is open, then i will conclude that A is closed. I know that $X$ is open, so is the difference of two open sets, an open set?

Answer (score 1):

In a discrete space, every subset is open. So take any subset $A$. it is open. Since its complement is open, $A$ is closed.

Comment: Isn't the complement of an open set a closed set?

Comment: @zermelovac Yes it is. That's exactly the point. The complement $A^c$ is also open, so *its* complement, $(A^c)^c = A$, is closed.